# getting a certain font

Tags: html, css

I am currently doing a recipe project that requires a certain font and I don't have the font and I am not sure how to go about getting it. The font style is called young serif I have a file with it but am unsure how to get it over to my visual studio.

Comment: My favorite source for fonts is Google Fonts. Looks like they have Young Serif: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Young+Serif . Here's the documentation on how to add a Google Font to your CSS: https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/css2

Comment: I need it for visual studio coding though

Comment: Just for clarification, do you have the font file (.ttf/.otf)? And you want to include it in your HTML CSS projects, right?

Comment: how do i check for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have 2ways for adding Young Serif from Google Fonts either in the head of your HTML file by adding this code as indicated in Google Fonts

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Young+Serif&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

or by adding this code into your CSS file

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Young+Serif&display=swap')
```

then to add the font in your class .myclass

```css
.myclass{
    font-family: "Young Serif", serif;
}
```

I Hope this help

Comment: Thank you so much I did not think I would have to import now I feel silly but it worked so thank you so much

Comment: You very welcome. if this answers your question please mark this answer as accepted

Answer (score 0):

I use always google fonts. In visual studio, there is an extension called "Google Fonts Insert Link", that when you insert a font name (that exists, of course) it inserts the link to google fonts. In your case, `young serif` font link would be like this:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Young+Serif:regular" rel="stylesheet" />
```

you have to insert the css code (in the Mehdi's answer) to change the `font-family`.

Hope this answers your question